# Error Code: 1329 No data rows fetched ,selected or processed (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

hello am getting the error of no data - zero rows fetched and trying to use the cursor to store the Employees Name( full name) for the
HR department into a variable called `emp_names`.

```
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
declare emp_id int;
    declare first_name varchar(30);
    declare last_name varchar(30);
    declare full_name varchar(60);
    declare is_done int default 0;   
    
    declare emp_c cursor for
    select emp_id, First_name,last_name
    from employee;
    
    open emp_c;
    
    getdata:loop
    fetch next from emp_c into emp_id,first_name,last_name;      
        if is_done =1 then 
            leave getdata;
        end if;        
    set full_name= concat(first_name," ",last_name); 
    end loop; 
    close emp_c;
    
END
```

Comment: Use common SELECT with GROUP_CONCAT() instead of your SP...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to learning about cursors and loops, else i would recommitment a single update  clause.

you need to declare always a `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` so that thw variable is_done gets  a new value when the loop is complete

> ```
> CREATE tABLE employee ( emp_id int, First_name varchar(30),last_name varchar(30),full_name varchar(60))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1,'a','b',''),(2,'c','d','')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
> BEGIN
> declare _emp_id int;
>     declare _first_name varchar(30);
>     declare _last_name varchar(30);
>     declare full_name varchar(60);
>     declare is_done int default 0;   
>     
>     declare emp_c cursor for
>     select emp_id, First_name,last_name
>     from employee;
>       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET is_done = 1;
>     open emp_c;
>     
>     getdata:loop
>     fetch next from emp_c into _emp_id,_first_name,_last_name; 
>
>         if is_done =1 then 
>             leave getdata;
>         end if;
>     set full_name= concat(_first_name," ",_last_name);
>     end loop; 
>     close emp_c;
>     
> END
> ```

> ```
> call new_procedure()
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22427f6abc03b0c76f3b02c042564cef)*